# Software to extract the list of References and title from a pdf of a Research paper?

Tags: pdf

I have about 8,000 pdfs of research papers and I want to extract their references and titles. Any ideas on software to do this?

Comment: Write 8000, to make it more easy to comprehend on the spot.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc: Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then **[edit]** your page and fill the gaps: What OS should the software run on? How much you'd willing to spend if it's paid? Etc ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/) is an online web service, reference library and desktop/mobile client software for multiple platforms that is specifically targeted at the research world. You can import PDF files to have them scanned for citations in various files and also for keywords to search on.

It also provides a lot of other very useful facilities for the researcher such as links to potential funding sources, collaborators, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [python](https://python.org) and `pip install refextract` which will then give you a facility to extract references from PDF files using the [refextract](https://pypi.org/project/refextract/) library. You could then use the python [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.walk) function to parse your entire collection adding the located references to a local database *(note that python comes with [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html) and can interface with most other databases)*.

```
>>> from refextract import extract_references_from_file
>>> references = extract_references_from_file('1503.07589.pdf')
>>> print(references[0])
{
    'author': [u'F. Englert and R. Brout'],
    'doi': [u'doi:10.1103/PhysRevLett.13.321'],
    'journal_page': [u'321'],
    'journal_reference': [u'Phys. Rev. Lett. 13 (1964) 321'],
    'journal_title': [u'Phys. Rev. Lett.'],
    'journal_volume': [u'13'],
    'journal_year': [u'1964'],
    'linemarker': [u'1'],
    'raw_ref': [u'[1] F. Englert and R. Brout, \u201cBroken symmetry and the mass of gauge vector mesons\u201d, Phys. Rev. Lett. 13 (1964) 321, doi:10.1103/PhysRevLett.13.321.'],
    'texkey': [u'Englert:1964et'],
    'year': [u'1964'],
}
```

- Free, gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java environment then you can have a look at CERMINE, a product from research paper in springer [CERMINE](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10032-015-0249-8).

Codes can be found at [Here](https://github.com/CeON/CERMINE).